# Python Anaconda Prompt: ¿Como acceder a una ruta de disco con espacios?

Tags: python, anaconda

En 'Anaconda Prompt' estoy intentando acceder a una ruta con espacios, introducida entre comillas, y me da el siguiente error:

```
cd "D:1- Programación\\2\"
```

El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.

La misma ruta la uso en el CMD de Windows y sí funciona.

Comment: El problema no son los espacios sino las barras. ¿Estás usando doble barra? es decir `d:\\1 - Programación`?

Answer (score 0):

En todos los lenguajes de programación existen las llamadas *secuencias de escape*, y se representan escribiendo en primer lugar una barra invertida (`\`).

Por ejemplo, para representar un salto de línea utilizarías la cadena `"\n"`, o para una tabulación `"\t"`.

Para representar una barra invertida debes utilizar `"\\"` (así indicas que no estás representando una secuencia de escape).

Otra opción es utilizar las barras no invertidas `"/"` para indicar la ruta (aunque estés en *Windows* funcionará).

Comment: Al final resulta que el error es, que Anaconda Prompt, al contrario que CMD, exige poner la barra después de la letra de unidad y los dos puntos, así:
D:\
y no así:
D: